# Problem with not always getting the raw file from the Camera2Raw sample program

Tags: android-camera2

I am having a problem with the sample program that comes with AndroidStudio. I only tried this on an S8, so I am not sure if this is a problem with this particular device or it's generic.

If I try to take multiple pictures in one shot, by setting mPendingUserCaptures to a number like 4, and especially if I manually set the exposure time to a low value (usually under 30ms or so), I ALWAYS get 4 JPG images, but sometimes I only get 3 raw files (the last one is missing).
The problem is in the ImageSaver class, which is not always called for the RAW file, but always for the JPG.

I was wondering, did anyone ever experience something like this, when a RAW image will sometimes not arrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after weeks of hunting this bug on and off, I finally found out what happened.
I posted the solution here, just in case someone else stumbles around this problem.

Sometimes the function public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) { dequeueAndSaveImage(mRawResultQueue, mRawImageReader); } would get called twice in a row.

The code was:

```
    Map.Entry<Integer, ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder> entry = pendingQueue.firstEntry();
    ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder builder = entry.getValue();
```

This creates a huge problem, because sometimes two images will be added to the same TreeMap entry, so if we have 4 entries, the last entry will never get its image :/

```
The fixed code (I left my extra logs there) looks like this:

   private void dequeueAndSaveImage(TreeMap<Integer, ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder> pendingQueue, RefCountedAutoCloseable<ImageReader> reader) {
        synchronized (mCameraStateLock) {

            ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder builder=null;
            Map.Entry<Integer, ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder> entry;
            int key=4;//shut up, stupid java shit
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder> ent : pendingQueue.entrySet()) {
                builder = ent.getValue();
                if(builder.mImage==null) {
                    key = ent.getKey();
                    break;
                }

            }

            //Map.Entry<Integer, ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder> entry = pendingQueue.firstEntry();
            //ImageSaver.ImageSaverBuilder builder = entry.getValue();
            Log.w(TAG, "StartingdequeueAndSaveImage, builder: " + builder);

            if(builder.mImage!=null)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Builder: " + builder + " already has an image!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }

            // Increment reference count to prevent ImageReader from being closed while we
            // are saving its Images in a background thread (otherwise their resources may
            // be freed while we are writing to a file).
            if (reader == null || reader.getAndRetain() == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Paused the activity before we could save the image," + " ImageReader already closed.");
                pendingQueue.remove(key);
                return;
            }

            Image image;
            try {
                image = reader.get().acquireNextImage();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Too many images queued for saving, dropping image for request: " + key);
                pendingQueue.remove(key);
                return;
            }

            builder.setRefCountedReader(reader).setImage(image);

            if(image==null)Log.e(TAG, "Cacatul de imagine e null...... Sa ma fut in mortii lor.");

            handleCompletionLocked(key, builder, pendingQueue);
            Log.e(TAG, "Call handled completed in deque" + pendingQueue);
        }
    }
```